# Impossible to deals with big number in web3.js transacation :

Tags: web3js, transactions, bignumber, overflow

I can't deals with big number (BN.js) with web3.js I have overflow error or i have execution reverted with BN.js library when I try add liquidity to pancakeswap pool.

By using BN.js

[image]

Without using BN.js

[image]

Comment: Can you share the web3 code involved? In some cases you have to initialize the number with a string "100000000".

Answer (score 0):

Welcome,
It seems this is a common issue:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62301960/unable-to-call-contract-function-from-web3-with-big-number-as-parameter

Please include your actual code for further troubleshooting, so that the error can be reproduced.